# Heroku and Django 2.x ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_auth'

Tags: django, heroku, django-rest-auth

I've installed django-rest-auth locally with Django 2.x and it works fine.
However, when I deploy to Heroku I get a "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_auth'" error.

I made sure that the requirements.txt is OK (pip freeze).
I also ran commands with CLI and the Heroku CL interface : pip install django-rest-auth

Any ideas why it's not working?

Comment: I don't use Heroku so I can only tell that normally strange module behavior is caused by some mix-up of users.
You have to make sure that the modules you need are installed for the user, that runs the Python Django process (is Heroku using Apache, then it might be www-data).

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer... I had to add the module ALSO to the pipfile and made sure to adapt the syntax like this :
In requirements.txt => **django-rest-auth==0.9.3**
In Pipfile => **django-rest-auth = "==0.9.3"**